# Singleton and Context

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-context

I have started learning android using Android Big Nerd Ranch guide. 
Listing 9.1 Setting up the singleton (CrimeLab.java)

```
public class CrimeLab {
    private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;
    private Context mAppContext;

    private CrimeLab(Context appContext) {
        mAppContext = appContext;
    }

    public static CrimeLab get(Context c) {
        if (sCrimeLab == null) {
            sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(c.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sCrimeLab;
    }
}
```

Project- we are creating list of crime objects and we used this class to store the list.

I am having trouble to understand the need of the Singleton class  provided in Listing 9.1. Why do we need this class in the first place? and why do wee need a context variable and what does it hold ?

I searched google and found out that context is used to inform what is going on with other parts of the application. However, I didn't quite get what are we informing CrimeLab about? Can we create crimeLab without a singleton class? if Yes, why we used crimeLab as a singleton class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an issue of Android, it's just a design pattern itself.
I have read this example in the Android Big Nerd Ranch guide. Listing 9.1 Setting up the singleton (CrimeLab.java) and the reason of having it in singleton was described by we want to store the *shared* data. Let imagine that when we construct the CrimeLab object without singleton in 2 places:

```
CrimeLab cb1 = new CrimeLab(context);
CrimeLab cb2 = new CrimeLab(context);
```

it creates the new objects and the stored data in cb1 and cb2 are different.

Let imagine about you are using database in the application, it should be *only one*? Yes.

But to target the same purpose (single data place), we can use the static methods or properties, but you need to prevent creating object by hiding the constructor

```
private CrimeLab(Context appContext) {
    mAppContext = appContext;
}
```

Comment: Oh! and we need context to tell the application what has happened so that all the data accumulate in one place nicely. Am I Right?  Thank you very much

Comment: No, we just need the context here if we *need* its information for CrimeLab object. Otherwise you can remove it as it's a parameter itself. The data is in one place just because of singleton implement (a static property):
private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;

Answer (score 0):

A singleton is a class of which there will only ever be at most one instance. Hence the private constructor and the public static get.

The public static get is often parameterless. And the reason is that if it is called with different parameters then the order of the call will cause the singleton to be initialized differently, thus you are prone to race conditions.

Without more context I only can conclude that such code is bad.